# Convert string payload of type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' to map of type 'application/java' in mule 3

Tags: string, http-post, mule, x-www-form-urlencoded

I have a requirement to read `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data as a request body from POST API, The content is in String format like below. How can we convert it to java.util.Map in **mule3**?

[image]

Please suggest!!

Comment: Can you share which Mule3 version: e.g. 3.9.1? Also, is this after a listener or request?

Comment: @RyanCarter This is mule 3.9.3, It is from listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any direct transformer support from mule3 for this, Found a workaround that is  split that by ',' and read the values individually, It solved my problem.